# ERROR 2013 (HY000) while connecting to Google Cloud Sql MySql database from mysql client

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Since yesterday, I am getting the following error while trying to connect to my Google Cloud SQL MySql database:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
My app is able to connect to the database, but I am unable to connect from my computer. I have configured my public ip address in Access Controls section.

I noticed one other thing. The public address I setup is not stored, and when I come back to the "Access Control" tab I see a different ip address from what I saved.

How do I access my Cloud SQL MySql instance through MySql client? Is there any other setting I need to do?

Comment: The IP that you whitelist on your Cloud SQL instsnce should not change. Are you sure is not your public IP the one that is changing?

Comment: Smells like a dynamic IP problem -- if that's the case, the advice at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#dynamicIP can help.  To verify the externally visible IP of your computer, visit e.g http://whatismyv6.com/ repeatedly and see if it's always the same... (assuming you're using IPv6 here, but even if you're on IPv4 that URL can help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this was a browser problem. The Google developer console on Mozilla was displaying the ip as updated although it was not updating it in the backend. I used Chrome to set this Access control in the Developer console and this worked fine.